# How to add the logo in email body

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service, massemailmessage

How to add the logo in HTML email body. I have use an apex class that send an notifications to customers.The below code is send an emails to customers ***`**but in email body the image/logo is not displayed**`*.** I am doing correct way or not.Some one can help me.

**Note:** Email are send to customers but logo is not displayed in the email body.

```
String subject     = '';
String body        = '';          
String logo        = '';  
subject ='Remainder Email';
body ='<html><body style="font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><image id="Logo" src="https://ap1.salesforce.com/resource/1399298684000/MyLogo"/>
Dear Customer, <br><br>Thank for Ordering';

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage conformemail = NEW Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
conformemail.setSubject(subject);
conformemail.setHtmlBody(body);                      
conformemail.setToAddresses(NEW String[]{ord.Order_status_email__c});            
Messaging.sendEmail(NEW Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{'abc@gamil.com'});
```

Answer (score 3):

Ramesh,
when displaying images in email you have to use externally accessible url.

the image source url you are using your email body is accessible only for authenticated users in salesforce

```
src="https://ap1.salesforce.com/resource/1399298684000/MyLogo"/
```

you have to use a url something like this

```
https://c.<instance>.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=<document_id>&oid=<organization_id
```

please [refer this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Why-images-stored-as-static-resources-cannot-be-seen-in-emails-sent-using-VF-email-templates-1327108316482&language=en_US) for more details

Comment: Yes you are correct,In my code I have specified dummy url. Actual url is same for you specified. I have tried actual URL but it displayed BLANK

Comment: did you try opening the image url in a different browser where you are not logged into salesforce ? can you share the image url here pls ?

Comment: I have tried different browser with out logged in  salesforce.It displayed in the browser.

Comment: I have specify the image height and width now the image is came in email body.